# Событие на изменение геометрии полигона (перетаскивание вершин)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

задача простая:

> Необходимо выбрать все метки попавшие в область полигона, а при изменении его области добавлять новые.

Работаю первый раз с api яндекс карт.
На данный момент есть такое решение:

```
 myPolygon.events.add('geometrychange', function () {
//если вершин больше 3 то ищем объекты в полигоне
if (myPolygon.geometry._coordPath._coordinates[0].length > 3) {
var result = ymaps.geoQuery(searchCollection);
var objectsInside = result.searchInside(myPolygon);          
objectsInside.each(function (geoObject) {
myCollection.add(geoObject);
});
}
});
```

Но беда вся в том, что этот евент срабатывает раньше чем изменятся границы полигона. Другими словами приходится два раза изменить границу (перетащить вершину, чтобы объекты попали в полигон).

Также, нашел здесь такое решение, но оно не подходит, т.к. монитор срабатывает один раз только при построении полигона (при перетаскивании вершин мышкой, не работает) .

```
var stateMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(myPolygon.geometry.state);
stateMonitor.add("editing /*пробовал разные стейты*/", function (newValue) {
});
```

К какому событию привязать можно, посоветуйте пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Все будет работать корректно, если поставить таймаут на обработку

```
polygon.events.add('geometrychange', function () {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        var objectsInsidePolygon = objects.searchInside(polygon);
        objectsInsidePolygon.setOptions('preset', 'islands#redIcon');
        objects.remove(objectsInsidePolygon).setOptions('preset', 'islands#blueIcon');
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqnzfd7m/3/

Судя по всему, изменение реальной геометрии делается в том же потоке исполнения и ваш колбек срабатывает раньше, чем сам объект подхватывает изменения.

UPD
Все будет работать корректно, если подписаться на pixelgeometrychange
https://jsfiddle.net/wqnzfd7m/5/